# Text color of link with "active" class

Tags: html, css

I have a navigation bar, and I need the active page, marked by "subactive" class on the li element to have white text instead of black. The HTML and CSS can be found here: http://jsfiddle.net/a4hBz/

I use color on the .subactive selector in CSS, but its ignored by the browser.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's largely due to how CSS "weighs" the styles. IDs **always** have more presidence over a standard tag name, class name or pseudo-class. A simple solution is to be as-specific with your anchor class applying the "Active" styling as you are with the rest of the standard elements. Basically:

```css
.subactive a
```

Should become

```css
#sidenav .subactive a
```

If that doesn't work for your schema, you'll need to either turn `#sidenav` in to a class, or work-around it some other way.

---

By the way, what I was referring to earlier is a style's [specificity](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#specificity). As it currently stands, your styles weigh in like so:

```css
#sidenav a              a=0, b=1, c=0, d=1 -> specificity = 0,1,0,1
.subactive a            a=0, b=0, c=1, d=1 -> specificity = 0,0,1,1
#sidenav .subactive a   a=0, b=1, c=1, d=1 -> specfiicity = 0,1,1,1
```

Almost think of it like this:

```
(a * 1000) + (b * 100) + (c * 10) + d
```

The style with the highest number wins.

Comment: Selectors level 3 throws out inline styles as those aren't related to selectors, so you get a triplet of values for specificity instead, with the fourth leftmost one out.

Comment: @BoltClock: I'm either getting tired, or that comment was unclear. Are you eluding to `style=""` overrides with regards to specificity?

Comment: What I meant was that specificity refers to selectors, so inline styles shouldn't have been counted hence their removal from the CSS3 spec for calculating specificity. They always override any CSS rules (where `!important` isn't concerned), but that's the cascade itself rather than specificity. In any case, it's just something interesting to note.

Comment: @BoltClock: It technically does have to do with specificity, but `a` is so high up on the scale, it trumps most anything else.  but you're right, worth mentioning. ;-)

Comment: That's the cascade, not specificity. There's a subtle difference between the two. Calculating selector specificity is one component of the cascade; deciding which styles to apply is another.

Comment: @BoltClock: If it had no relevance, it wouldn't be given the `a` property. ;-) On a more subtle note I do see your point but the fact that is is or is not embedded in a style tag does have bearing on the end "score", albeit a **very** big weight as compared to the other properties.

Comment: Yeah, I'm just being pedantic and going off on a tangent here... :)

Answer (score 1):

Either add `!imporatant`:

```
.subactive a
{
    color: #fff!important;

    /**/

}
```

Or increase the `specificity` of the definition:

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#specificity

Comment: I always try to avoid `!important` as it was one of those attributes that was designed for the end-user and overriding styles in cases of accessibility. Though feasible, it's my humble opinion to avoid using it as much as possible.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use the !important if I didn't need to.

To make it work I would replace the line

```
#sidenav a:hover, .subactive a
```

to

```
#sidenav a:hover, #sidenav .subactive a:link
```

and remove the code below which doesn't seem to be used

```
.subactive a
{
   color: #fff;
   background-color: #034676;
}
```

​
Check out the working example on http://jsfiddle.net/a4hBz/1/

Comment: Gentle reminder, SO is a great resource because the question and answer are generally found on the same page. Though the solution you submitted to jsFiddle works and is referenced, it's always a good idea to post what your changes are in your answer here in case (days/months/years) from now someone wanted the solution but your link was no longer valid. Other than that, welcome to SO!

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I will keep building my capacity to answer questions in the best way possible. Thanks