# Two CSS Classes: Which one Wins?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

The markup below aligns `SAMPLE TEXT` to the left.

To me, it seems like it should be aligned to the right. The class that aligns to the right is declared after the one that aligns left. And the class that aligns to the right is even referenced last. So why does the class that aligns to the left win?

**CSS**

```
.table {
    width: 100%;
}
.table td {
    text-align: left;
}
.cell {
    text-align: right;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <td class="cell">
             SAMPLE TEXT
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>​
```

Please see my [jsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/VTrEE/).

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The `.table td` selector has a higher [specificity](http://www.htmldog.com/guides/cssadvanced/specificity/). CSS specificity rules are kind of weird... IDs weigh more than class names, which weigh more than tag names.

The specificity rules, in a nutshell:

- For each tag name, add 1.
- For each class name, add 10.
- For each ID, add 100.

The higher values will always override the lower ones. In the case of a tie, the last rule loaded wins.

Comment: Specificity values are not counted in decimal numbers. The specificity of `.table td` is *not* 11 (eleven) in base 10, but in some imaginary high base, meaning a rule with 12 type selectors isn't going to take precedence over that. So, it's weird like that.

Comment: Thanks. Could you clarify that last bit? If class names weigh more than tag names, doesn't that mean `.cell` outweighs `.table td`?

Comment: @Jonathan Wood: No, in this case you have `.cell`, which is a class selector, and `.table td,` which is a class selector *plus* a type selector, so it wins.

Comment: @BoltClock What base are the values in if not 10? I don't think I understand what you mean. The way I read [this](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#specificity), the value would be 11. Can you maybe explain this in a separate answer if you have time?

Comment: both are equal in a sense that both have classes (both have 1-0), but one has an element, which adds 1. so `.table td` = 1-1 (some sort of eleven) while `.cell` has 1-0 (some sort of 10). 1-1 is higher, thus `.table td` wins

Comment: @GGG what Bolt means is that if you add up tag to 10 or more, the value will not carry over to the other digit. it goes on like 1-10, 1-11, 1-12 (class-tag)

Comment: Wait, why is this paragraph (http://jsfiddle.net/xXaP5/) green then if IDs are 100 points and classes are 10 points?

Comment: @GGG: Well, forget about the bases thing, that's mentioned by the Selectors spec but isn't a great explanation. A better way to think of this is to just count each kind of selector separately. Or see Joseph's comment.

Comment: @David Faux: Your class is being applied to the `<p>` element, while your ID is on the `<div>`, so specificity becomes irrelevant here.

Comment: Oh, so it's got to be on the same element, otherwise selectors pertinent to the inner element wins. Thanks, got it.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/xXaP5/1/ here's proof when styles are applied on the same element using classes and ID - ID takes precedence.

Comment: @DavidFaux, I think you should [read the spec on inheritance](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#inheritance).

Comment: @BoltClock gotcha, so it's more like 200.30.5 or something... yeah that is weird.

Comment: Funnily, a day after this question was posted, somebody else asked why 13 classes don't beat an ID + 2 classes, giving me a short-lived opportunity to explain it in greater detail: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9540339/why-cant-i-beat-an-id-with-multiple-classes

Comment: @BoltClock hahah, feel free to fix this one up. I started editing that stuff in and couldn't find a way to explain it that wasn't confusing or really wordy (arbitrary base numbers, etc.).

Answer (score 6):

I highly recommend reading the actual [CSS specification on specificty](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#specificity).

There are four levels:

1. inline-styles, `!important` <sub>(a)</sub>
2. IDs <sub>(b)</sub>
3. classes, pseudo-classes, attribute selectors <sub>(c)</sub>
4. element, pseudo-elements <sub>(d)</sub>

For every selector, add one to it's respective letter category:

```
#foo.bar baz -> a=0, b=1, c=1, d=1
#fizz#buzz   -> a=0, b=2, c=0, d=0
```

`a` trumps `b` trumps `c` trumps `d`.

If there's a tie the second one wins:

```
#foo #bar baz
#fizz #buzz baz  <-- same specificity, this one wins
```

Comment: Inline styles are no longer part of calculating selector specificity as of level 3, as they are not selectors.

Comment: I hadn't known that, but after [scanning the level 3 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#specificity), you're right. I'm going to leave them in though because they *do* override the stylesheet values, and are important to remember in debugging specificity issues. Besides, the level 3 spec references the level 2 spec in how `[style]` values work.

Comment: Indeed. That's more of a cascading issue, though, but [I should try not to confuse anyone any further](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9492857/106224).

Answer (score 3):

styles of `text-align` by `.table td` will win over the `text-align` applied by `cell`

.table td specificity is (1-1) :

(10 x 1 class selector) + (1 x 1 element selector)

.cell specificity is (1-0) :

(10 x 1 class selector)

for `.cell` to win, it has to have a specificity higher than the others. It can also be equal to others but it has to be declared after the others of the same level.

[read more about inheritance and specificity](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/inheritancecascade)

Answer (score 1):

If you do

```
.table {
    width: 100%;
}
.table td {
    text-align: left;
    color: Yellow;
    background-color: Red;
}
td.cell {
    text-align: right;
}
```

it will right align http://jsfiddle.net/VTrEE/4/

Comment: Both the last two rules have same value but the last rule scanned gets the precedence thus the text aligns itself right. If you keep the '.table td' rule at the end, that will apply.